# SQL Query to search partial data in one field

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in mysql:

```
file-id
32-534
32-536
32-537
32-584
32-594
46-865
46-863
46-837
46-867
```

I want to write SQL query to enlist all the data with either 32- or 46-. How can I do that?

```
Select * from TABLE WHERE file-id = ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE file-id REGEXP '^32' OR file-id REGEXP '^46';
```

Comment: REGEXPs are more expensive than LIKEs, and not quoting `file-id` will most likely mean that the query is interpreted as subtracting  "id" from "file" (ie, probably an invalid query).

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 'file-id' LIKE '32-%' OR 'file-id' LIKE '46-%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE file-id REGEXP '^(32|46)';
```

Comment: REGEXPs are more expensive than LIKEs, and not quoting `file-id` will most likely mean that the query is interpreted as subtracting  "id" from "file" (ie, probably an invalid query).